# EF1 allow separate POCO entities

Tags: entity-framework, poco

I am using Entity Framework 1 (we must use .NET 3.5 SP1 to work and co-ordinate with SharePoint) and we are using an N-tier architecture:

Application Server (hosted in IIS)
 - data layer Entity Framework 
 - service layer (WCF)

Presentation Server (inside SharePoint 2010 WebPart)
 - proxy layer
 - presentation layer

Now we need to be able to share entities across the domain.

There is the option to use svcutil or add a web reference to create our proxy classes on the client side.

I am looking though, to be able to define the simple POCO entities in a separate assembly to share across tiers.

I know in EF4 I can do that (and have done that before) using the POCO Entity generator.

Is there a way to do this in EF1 - that is have the simple class definitions separate from the edmx (and thus decoupled)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFv1 doesn't have support for POCO entities. The only way around this is using [EF POCO adapter](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter).

Comment: I had a look at that and it is mentioned that it is a sample and is not supported at all.

Comment: Yes. That is just some code on top of EFv1 that shows how to use POCOs. If you don't like it you can create your own custom solution. The point is: No supported POCO approach with EFv1.

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution that will require more time to implement :
 First Create a .net 4.1 or greater class library project
 Add EF + POCO.
 Generate Repository Interface and implementation with T4.
 Now you have just to copy POCO classses to another project (.net 3.5)
 Implement Repository in ADO.NET  (don't require so much effort)

THis way, the day you migrate to .net >4 you will be happy that you have everithing ready.

I am doing this way in my projects(.net 4.5) because i find ado.net much faster than EF but i like autogeneration of POCO and Repository. The best of the two worlds/